# Terminated App Due to Memory Pressure when switching views

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I have an NSArray of views where each view contains a custom way of displaying a panoramic image. Each of these views contains 6 images where each image is the face of a cube and you are viewing from the center of the cube. I've compressed the images down to < 200kb jpegs and the images are UIImages that use 'initWithContentsOfFile' rather than 'imageNamed' so they aren't cached in memory.

I have Next/Back buttons for cycling through them but when I am running it on my device and I am cycling through them using the Next button, the app crashes with "Terminated App Due to Memory Pressure". From what I can tell using instruments, after I change the view the memory usage spikes to 200mb+ and then falls back to <5mb for reasons that I cannot tell. The relevant code is below (simplified):

```
- (void)nextPano:(id)sender
{    
    if (pictureIndex < [viewList count])
    {
        pictureIndex++;
        self.view = [viewList objectAtIndex:(pictureIndex)];  
    }
}
```

I am fairly new to iOS development so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Instruments should be also indicating the amount of memory consumption for all allocated objects.  Are you seeing abnormally high consumption for anything specific?  Also, roughly how many images are you loading into memory? Which instrument are you using?

Comment: @Jeremy I'm looking at the Leaks and Allocations one. At no point throughout using the program do I see any allocations > 10mb (including right before crashing). Am I looking in the right place?

Comment: @Jeremy Regarding how many images i'm loading, for testing right now i'm loading 4 different views so 24 images. But i'm lazily loading them so that they aren't all in memory at once. 


I removed it from the code I posted here but before self.view is set to the new view, the new view has its images initialized. The way this is done is that each view stores the names of the images that they need to load as NSString's.

Comment: Something to consider is the possibility that there is burst memory usage, or memory that is being allocated within a loop which wouldn't have been immediately released by an autorelease pool.  For example, could one of the views be drawing something to superimpose on the image?